# How can I add "All Authenticated users" (FBA) to a SharePoint Group using Powershell?

Tags: 2010, powershell, security

I have an FBA site and I need to add "all authenticated users" to a group using PowerShell. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add All Authenticated Users in FBA site. You can do it in Windows sites only. There is however a work around as suggested in this link by creating a role in the directory service, add all existing users to it.
[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bgeoffro/adding-an-all-authenticated-users-feature-to-forms-based-authentication)

I wonder whether the link provided by you will be of any help. But here is the Powershell equivalent of that code:

```
$Url = "http://sitename"
                $GroupName = "group name"
                $PermissionLevel = "Read"
                $Description = "group description"              
                $web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $Url
                if ($web.SiteGroups[$GroupName] -ne $null)
                {
                                Write-Host "Group $GroupName already exists!" -foregroundcolor Red
                }
                else
                {
                                $web.SiteGroups.Add($GroupName, $web.Site.Owner, $web.Site.Owner, $Description)
                                $group = $web.SiteGroups[$GroupName]
                                $roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($group)
                                $roleDefinition = $web.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions[$PermissionLevel]
                                $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition)
                                $web.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)
                                $web.Update()
                                Write-Host "Group $GroupName created successfully" -foregroundcolor Green
                }
                $user = "c:0(.s|true"
                $web.SiteGroups[$GroupName].AddUser($user, "", "","")               
                $web.Dispose()
```

Comment: I found this suggestion here: http://www.sharemuch.com/2011/12/06/how-to-automatically-add-all-authenticated-users-to-sharepoint-security-group/ was wondering how to do it in powershell.

Comment: It's not possible, like Nadeem correctly answered earlier (+1 !)
To solve your issue, you can add all required FBA *roles* to the relevant SP built-in group (or create a new one for the case). Since all user should belong to at least one group, you'll add them all in the end. (and you won't need to add a new "AllUsers" group in your FBA Role / Membership. The powershell displayed above will put you on road provided that you have in hand all role to add.